# How to get Javascript array result into Java?

Tags: java, javascript, scripting, rhino

I want to use ScriptEngine of Java but I have some trouble with javascript split function like below:

```
    ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("javascript");
    Bindings bindings = engine.createBindings();
    bindings.put("example", "123/456/789");

    String s1 = "var obj = example.split(\"/\"); print(obj[0]);";

    Object result = engine.eval(s1, bindings);

    System.out.println(result);
```

when I evaluate the script; this code prints "123null" because result is null. When I tried return statement instead of print like this:

```
    String s1 = "var obj = example.split(\"/\"); return obj[0];";
```

throws an exception:

*Exception in thread "main" javax.script.ScriptException: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EvaluatorException: invalid return (#1) in  at line number 1*

So how should I get the value of first index from this splitted native array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
var obj = example.split(\"/\"); obj[0];
```